# How to search for value in all descendant textNodes(Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So basically I am making a Chrome extension which sorts the search results on Ebay by their popularity(number of times sold). To do this I need to find all `li` elements which have a descendant text node containing the text `...+ Sold` where `...` is a number.
Basically, search results on Ebay look like this:

```
<li class="s-item">
   <div class="s-item__wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="s-item__image-section">
         <!-- other stuff -->
      </div>
      <div class="s-item__info clearfix">         
         <!-- other stuff -->
         <div class="s-item__details clearfix">
            <!-- other stuff -->
            <div><span><span>62+ Sold</span></span></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

In every `li` element I have to search for the text `Sold` and extract the number out of that text node to process it further. How can I do that?

Comment: Use TreeWalker API which is the fastest one for this task, see [getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes](//stackoverflow.com/a/2579869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that only by using `childNodes` or `children` properties because they return only the children and not all descendants of the current node. So you will have to write your own function for that, something like:

```
function getDescendants(node, arr) {
      var i;
      arr = arr || [];
      for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
          arr.push(node.childNodes[i])
          getDescendants(node.childNodes[i], arr);
      }
      return arr;
  }
```

Using this function, you just simply iterate over all descendants and check if they are text nodes ( `nodeType == 3` ) and after that search for the word `Sold` in them. Extracting the number is pretty easy after that.
Something like:

```
var searchValue = "Sold";
var descendants = getDescendants(listItem);
for(var j = 0; j < descendants.length; j++) {
    if(descendants[j].nodeType == 3){
        if(descendants[j].nodeValue.indexOf(searchValue) > -1){
            var text = descendants[j].nodeValue.trim();
            //"37+ Sold"    for example
            var soldNr = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(searchValue)-2);  
            //you process your number(soldNr) further
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is more general and it would work in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

Use a selector string: select `li.s-item span` to select all `span`s which descend from an `li` with a class of `s-item`, check to see if the span's only child is a text node with "Sold" in it, and if so, do whatever you need to do with it.

If you're sure that *any* `<li>` will do, and not just those with a class of `s-item`, then use `'li span'` instead:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li span').forEach(({ childNodes, textContent }) => {
  if (childNodes.length !== 1 || childNodes[0].nodeType !== 3 || !textContent.includes('Sold')) return;
  const count = textContent.match(/\d+/);
  console.log('Processing span with sold number ' + count);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="s-item">
    <div class="s-item__wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="s-item__image-section">
        <!-- other stuff -->
      </div>
      <div class="s-item__info clearfix">
        <!-- other stuff -->
        <div class="s-item__details clearfix">
          <!-- other stuff -->
          <div><span><span>62+ Sold</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="s-item">
    <div class="s-item__wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="s-item__image-section">
        <!-- other stuff -->
      </div>
      <div class="s-item__info clearfix">
        <!-- other stuff -->
        <div class="s-item__details clearfix">
          <!-- other stuff -->
          <div><span><span>333+ Sold</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem I see with this solution is that if Ebay changes the name of the class, it would not work anymore

Comment: OK, you edited the code, it works in every case now :)